# List Button in Sub implementation of Interface vb.net has count always 0

Tags: vb.net, list, button, interface

I have trouble with my list of Button in vb.net, that has always count = 0 when sub was run. 
Here're my code :
Interface :

```
 Public Interface ICheckBox
    Sub check(index)
End Interface
```

Form testing  that implement interface ICheckBox :

```
Public Class FmTesting
    Implements ICheckBox
    Private listBtnQuestion As New List(Of Button)
 Sub check(index) Implements ICheckBox.check
        Me.listBtnQuestion.Item(index).BackColor = Color.Cyan
    End Sub

 Private Sub FmTesting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   'Item is my custom User Controls 
      Item.iCheckbox = New FmTesting
        'GroupBox
        Dim w As Integer = 24
        Dim h As Integer = 37
        Dim sizeW As Integer = 47
        Dim sizeH As Integer = 32

        For i = 1 To 20
            Dim btn As New Button
            btn.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(w, h)
            btn.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4)
            btn.Name = "Button1"
            btn.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(sizeW, sizeH)
            btn.TabIndex = 0
            btn.Text = i
            btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
            listBtnQuestion.Add(btn)
            Me.gbSubject.Controls.Add(btn)
            w = w + sizeW + 4
            If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
                h = h + sizeH + 4
                w = 24

            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

In my Item custom User Control I create interface :

```
   Private _iCheckBox As ICheckBox
        Public Property iCheckbox() As ICheckBox

            Get
                Return _iCheckBox
            End Get
            Set(value As ICheckBox)
                _iCheckBox = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

I debug that show listBtnQuestion always has count = =0 in sub check(index) . But in other sub it has count = 20 .
I don't know how to fix that problem. Please help me! 
Thank you!

Comment: How EXACTLY are you calling that method?  My guess is that you're calling it from outside the form and you're using the default instance and you haven't actually shown the default instance.

Comment: I've edit my question. Do u have any advice for me?

Comment: That would mean that you would have to assign to that `iCheckbox` property the same instance of `FmTesting` that you are showing.  Are you doing that?  If you are then I don't see why it wouldn't work as you expect, which suggests that you're not.  How EXACTLY are you setting that property and how EXACTLY are you displaying an instance of that form?

Comment: So, How should I initialize my  Item.iCheckbox ?

Comment: I've told you what you should be doing already and I have also asked you a question that you haven't bothered answering.  I can't give you the exact code you should use because it depends on the code you already have.  I asked you for more information because I need it to help you further.  If you don't want to answer then that's your prerogative but then I'm not going to help you.  When a stranger volunteers their time to help you, the least you can do is provide an answer when they ask a question.

Comment: ok. I'm sorry! it's my fault

Comment: For the record, I'm happy to help further and I tend not to hold a grudge but if I ask for information it's generally because I need it in order to be able to help you.

Comment: yep, I got it. I wounder about my lack of information of vb.net . So, Could you send me any example about interface in vb.net ?